# SSMS Import and Export Wizard - Error importing excel data

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My dev machine setup:

- Windows 10 64bit
- Office 2016 64bit
- SSMS 17.6

I connect to a machine running SQL Server 2016 64bit.

I am trying to import data into my database using an excel file.  When i try, i get the dreaded error The ‘Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0’ provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data).

I have tried selecting different version of excel, no difference except the ACE version.  I have searched and read many posts on the topic, which hasnt helped.  Ive followed several different things that worked for different people.  Tried installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable both 64 and 32 bits.  I have tried the 2010 Redistributables, no luck.

All of these i cant find the Import and Export Wizard (64bit) version.  I only have the 32bit version.

What else can I try?

Comment: If you run `odbcad32` does the driver show?

Comment: not in 32 but, but in 64 bit it does

Comment: When you say you "Tried installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable both 64 and 32 bits" you mean it installed successfuly but didn't solve your problem or it didn't install at all?

Comment: Yes, I installed successfully but it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: Do i want to install the 32bit or 64bit version of the access database engine?

Answer (score 0):

This isnt really an answer, just how I fixed it.  I uninstalled almost everything sql related. Ran a repair on my Visual Studio installed to reinstall anything I might have uninstalled in the previous step.  I then reinstalled SMSS.  I then installed the AccessDatabaseEngine 32bit version.  That got it working again.